# How to move jenkins multi-branch pipeline job workspace

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I've moved the Jenkins workspace (`/var/lib/jenkins/workspace`) to another volume via `localhost:8080/configure` → `Home directory` → Advanced → `Workspace Root Directory`: `/vol3/jenkins/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}`.  That change, however, is disregarded by my multi-branch pipeline jobs.  I still see them at `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace`.  Is this something I need to configure in the `Jenkinsfile`?

Jenkins version: 2.53

Comment: related? https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39667